# Checking for new software updates to the client

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api, windows-phone, json.net

I have written a very simple web service with MVC and WebApi. Now I'm working on the client code which will be a WPF application (and soon Windows 8 Store/Phone app). What I have done works, but I'm not sure I'm doing it the "right" way. The purpose of the service is to check if there are any new software updates to the client.

My server code looks like this (simplified):

```
public class ProductVersionsController : ApiController
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    [HttpGet]
    public CheckVersionResult CheckVersion(string product, string platform, string version)
    {
        CheckVersionResult result = new CheckVersionResult();

        //Logic removed...

        return result;
    }
}
```

My client code looks like this (simplified):

```
string parameters = "product=myproduct&platform=wpf&version=1.2.3.4";
string CheckUrl = "http://localhost:61933/api/ProductVersions/CheckVersion";

var url = new Uri(CheckUrl + "?" + parameters);
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    var json = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);

    CheckVersionResult data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CheckVersionResult>(json);

    //Logic removed...
}
```

The deserializing is done with [Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

Should I use `HttpGet` for a service like this, or should I use `Post` to send the parameters? How the parameters are sent feels a bit clumsy. If the parameters were encapsulated in a class, how should that be solved on the client side? Is there any good practice I have missed?

Comment: Have you considered using something like WCF, where a method invocation is translated into a network request automatically?

Comment: I know barely anything about WCF but I guess there is no support for that in Windows 8 store apps (I missed to mention that - question updated). But I'm gladly wrong about this :-).

Comment: What did you simplify exactly? Is the `parameters` string usually built up in code rather than hard-coded like that?

Comment: For now the `parameters` string is build like that, which I don't like an plan to improve. Otherwise my only simplification is that I have removed code that isn't directly related to the communication.

Comment: @PEK I would use GET as your not changing anything on the  serverside.

Comment: Any final _solution_ with **full source code** sample application ? _IMHO, better samples for minimize learning curve are real 

applications with full source code and good patterns_

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t have any full source code sample and don’t have time to make one. But I think you could create a client example fairly easy with the code I posted below. There is three helper classes you don’t need to change. And then you need to adjust the example code to your web service. Just take it gently and take one step at the time and you probably will make it work :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I will answer myself, hopefully someone else has use of this.

When it comes to the server side, I'll let it be like it is. Using HttpGet could be useful for caching so that's a good thing.

The client code works but it's a bit messy so decided to clean it up with some simple helper classes. In these classes I'm using `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient`. `WebClient` isn't available on Windows Phone/Store apps, but `HttpClient` could be used if in wpf if you put a reference to `System.Net.Http`.

I have also replaced [Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) with `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer`. The benefits with this is that this is supported in the framework in all platforms. The downside is that some variable types (like `DateTime`) can't be parsed directly.  But in my application this is fairly easy to deal with, and I prefer to add some extra lines of code than a large library.

This is my replacement for [Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json):

```
public class JsonHelper
{
    public static string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        EnsureHasDataContractAttribute(type);

        System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer serializer =
                        new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);

            byte[] rawData = stream.ToArray();

            return System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rawData, 0, rawData.Length);
        }
    }

    public static object Deserialize(string text, Type type)
    {
        EnsureHasDataContractAttribute(type);

        System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer a =
                        new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(type);

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)))
        {
            return a.ReadObject(stream);
        }
    }

    public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string text)
    {
        return (T)Deserialize(text, typeof(T));
    }

    private static void EnsureHasDataContractAttribute(Type attributeHolder)
    {
        // I have had problems with classes where [DataContract]/[DataMember] is
        // is missing. This has caused DataContractJsonSerializer to crash
        // randomly. This method make a simple check that the
        // [DataContract] attribute is added to the class. Not perfect
        // but should catch mose problems I hope.

        //String is always safe
        if (attributeHolder == typeof(string))
            return;

        //decimal is always safe
        if (attributeHolder == typeof(decimal))
            return;

        //Primtives is always safe
        if (attributeHolder.GetTypeInfo().IsPrimitive)
            return;

        //Enums is always safe
        if (attributeHolder.GetTypeInfo().IsEnum)
            return;

        //byte[] could cause problems.
        if (attributeHolder == typeof(byte[]))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Type byte[] is behaving differently in DataContractJsonSerializer and JSon.Net. You should probably use string and Convert.FromBase64String instead");
            return;                    
        }

        //DateTime/DateTimeOffset could cause problems.
        if (attributeHolder == typeof(DateTime) || attributeHolder == typeof(DateTimeOffset))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Type DateTime/DateTimeOffset is behaving differently in DataContractJsonSerializer and JSon.Net. You should probably use string and DateTime/DateTimeOffset.Parse instead");
            return;
        }

        //TimeSpan could cause problems.
        if (attributeHolder == typeof(TimeSpan))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Type TimeSpan is behaving differently in DataContractJsonSerializer and JSon.Net. You should probably use string and DateTime/DateTimeOffset.Parse instead");
            return;
        }

        // If this is a collection, check the elemnt type instead.
        Type subType = attributeHolder.GetElementType();

        if( subType != null )
        {
            EnsureHasDataContractAttribute(subType);
            return;
        }

        // Check that DataContractAttribute is added to the type.
        // Note: using System.Reflection; is needed for GetTypeInfo.
        if (attributeHolder.GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttribute(typeof(System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute)) != null)
            return;

        // Oh no! [DataContract] is missing on the type that should de deserialized!
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

        throw new Exception("Missing [DataContract] for " + attributeHolder.ToString());
    }
}
```

I have also written a small class to build the Uri with all parameters:

```
public class UriQueryBuilder
{
    public UriQueryBuilder()
        : this(null, null)
    {

    }

    public UriQueryBuilder(string baseurl)
        : this(baseurl, null)
    {
    }

    public UriQueryBuilder(string baseurl, string action)
    {
        Parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        BaseUrl = baseurl;
        Action = action;
    }

    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters { get; set; }

    public string QueryString
    {
        get
        {
            var array = (from key in Parameters.Keys
                         select string.Format("{0}={1}", System.Uri.EscapeDataString(key), System.Uri.EscapeDataString(Parameters[key])))
                            .ToArray();

            return string.Join("&", array);
        }
    }

    public string FormattedUri
    {
        get
        {
            string formattedString = BaseUrl;

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Action))
            {
                if (!BaseUrl.EndsWith("/"))
                    formattedString += "/";

                formattedString += Action;
            }

            string query = QueryString;

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
            {
                formattedString += "?";

                formattedString += query;
            }

            return formattedString;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I wrote HttpHelper that takes care of the downloading part. Note that there is support of `CancelleationTokenSource`. I want that the user should be able to stop everything immediately if needed.

```
public class HttpHelper
{
    public static async Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(UriQueryBuilder builder, CancellationTokenSource cancelHandler = null)
    {   
        var url = new System.Uri(builder.FormattedUri);
        using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            if (cancelHandler != null)
                cancelHandler.Token.Register(client.CancelPendingRequests);

            return await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<T> DownloadJsonObjectAsync<T>(UriQueryBuilder builder, CancellationTokenSource cancelHandler = null)
    {
        string text = await DownloadStringAsync(builder, cancelHandler);

        return JsonHelper.DeserializeObject<T>(text);
    }
}
```

**Example of usage**

First, define a class that will hold the parsed json data:

```
[DataContract]
public class CheckVersionResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool HasUpdate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string DownloadUrl { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ReleaseDateParsed
    { 
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return DateTime.Parse(ReleaseDate);
            }
            catch(Exception )
            {
                return new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` is needed for the `DataContractJsonSerializer`. ReleaseDateParsed is dirty but acceptable in my case.

Finally some code to build up the Uri and download and parse the data:

```
UriQueryBuilder builder = new UriQueryBuilder("http://localhost:61933/api/ProductVersions", "CheckVersion");
builder.Parameters.Add("product", "myproduct");
builder.Parameters.Add("platform", "wpf");
builder.Parameters.Add("version", "1.2.3.4");

CheckVersionResult data = await HttpHelper.DownloadJsonObjectAsync<CheckVersionResult>(builder, null);
```

Quite small and elegant I think. The best thing is that all code works in Wpf, Windows Store and Windows Phone apps.

Answer (score 6):

---

Simplified, examplified, trimmed code is frowned upon on this site; I'm surprised this question hasn't received any close votes yet.

I don't see anything blatantly done wrong here - I like . On the other hand if the client code you've shown is cohesively written in a specialized service (class) with a clear, focused interface that your *ViewModel*  receives as a constructor parameter and assigns to a `private readonly` field, then you've probably done the [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) part right.

If that very same code is written in some `Button1_Click` handler in your *View*'s code-behind, it could be the most cleverly written, beautifully crafted little piece of code, it would still be horribly misplaced.

`</rant>`

---

I still have a couple of things to say about your code:

> ```
> private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
> ```

The `db` identifier is misleading. I prefer to use `context` over `db`, because `db` refers to a *database*; a *context*, or *data context*, is more accurate. That said, by `new`ing up your context inside your controller, you have *tightly coupled* your controller with the specific `ApplicationDbContext` class.

The `Controller` class implements `IDisposable`; you should override the `Dispose` method and properly dispose of your `ApplicationDbContext` instance.

An alternative would be to *depend on an abstraction* instead:

```
private readonly IDbContext context;
```

The *dependency* can then be *constructor-injected*, and the `Controller` doesn't care what the actual implementation is, it's simply calling methods defined by some interface.

This would greatly improve the controller's *testability*.

---

> ```
> CheckVersionResult result = new CheckVersionResult();
> ```

I'm not a fan of this verbose notation; I find `result` is screaming its type at me, and I don't need that.

```
var result = new CheckVersionResult();
```

I find `var` makes more concise code that literally reads as "there's a variable here called *result* that we're going to assign to a new instance of the *CheckVersionResult* type" - as opposed to "there's a variable here of type *CheckVersionResult* called *result* that we're going to assign to a new instance of the *CheckVersionResult* type". But it boils down to personal preference I guess.

What isn't about personal preference, is consistency. Why is the client code different?

> ```
> var url = new Uri(CheckUrl + "?" + parameters);
> using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
> {
>     var json = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
> ```

..and the next line goes:

> ```
> CheckVersionResult data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CheckVersionResult>(json);
> ```

<s>I really prefer `var`</s> *I don't mind either notation*, but using both interchangeably is wrong.

---

I like that you're using `await`. This means you've written this code in an `async` method. That method's name should return a `Task` or a `Task<T>`, and have an `Async` suffix in its name, to follow convention.